# Close fuction dosen´t work when I try with tab or not in Python

Tags: python, fclose

I have been trying to solve this easy problem, however, I really don't understand why keeps happening!
My python script:

```
import re
#### PART 1
#### FIRST: we create a dictionary (an analog of a perl hash)
#### using the file containing two columns= IDS and labels

fileSet = {} ## empty dictionary

fb = open('NT_ID_S.csv', 'r')
for line2 in fb:
    if not line2: break
    line2 = line2.rstrip("\n")
    (ax, bx) = line2.split(";")
    fileSet[ax] = bx
fb.close()
#### PART 2
#### NOW, we will open our main file and apply while loops to
#### search in parts of every line (nested loops)

f = open('S_dN_dS_Tajima.tsv', 'r')
for line in f: # For main file (with 6 columns)
    if not line: break
    line = line.rstrip("\n")
    (a, b, c, d, e, f) = line.split("\t")
    if (a == "ID1"): continue  ### continue is like "next" in perl; it omits the first line (column names)
    if (a == b): continue  ### continue is like "next" in perl; it omits lines where the two IDs are the same

    #### Defining empty variables for the future new labels
    a3 = None
    b3 = None

    #### now, we will use the same FOR loop to obtain the value
    #### for the labels for the first and second IDs
    for key, value in fileSet.items():
        if (a == key):
            a3 = value
        elif (b == key):
            b3 = value

    #### Printing the final line with the new labels
    print (a, "\t", b, "\t", c, "\t", d,"\t", e, "\t", f, "\t", a3 , "\t", b3, "\t", end="\n")
f.close()
```

The error (in the second part of the script):

```
 File "merge_two_files_JP_v2.py", line 41, in <module>
    f.close()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I know that the problem is with "f.close", first I tried to change the tab position but the same error happens, then I use the tab position, however the same happens again.
I really don´t understand why doesn't work.

Comment: ``(a, b, c, d, e, f) = line.split("\t")`` overwrites ``f`` with a string. Use proper, speaking names that do not collide and this won't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reassign `f` here :

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f) = line.split("\t")
```

So after this point `f` isn't a file - it is a string.

This is a good time to learn meaningful variable naming.

Comment: thank you, the error was very small, I really couldn't see it. Anyway, thank you again!

Comment: Amit's suggestion of using with is good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is the following:

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f) = line.split("\t")
```

You change the value of f to a string value.

A solution if to change the name of the variable f in that line and use f for the file.

Answer (score 1):

you are reassigning to f variable at

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f) = line.split("\t")
```

You need to change variable name other that `f`.

ALso you can use with open so you dont need to close the file

```
with open(filename ) as fp:
    #your logic
```

Comment: Using with is a very good idea.